# Liquibase use added function in index does not work for postgres database

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

i use the following changeset in liquibase to add a function to an existing database

```
<changeSet author="me" id="2">
<sqlFile encoding="UTF-8"
         path="add_function_my_timestamp.sql"
         relativeToChangelogFile="true"
         splitStatements="false"
         stripComments="false"
         endDelimiter=";"/>
```

The content of the sql file (add_function_my_timestamp.sql) is

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.my_timestamp(some_time timestamp without time zone) RETURNS timestamp with time zone
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
AS $_$
select date_trunc('day', cast($1 AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin' as date))
       $_$;
```

Liquibase tells me migration was successful

```
SQL in file add_function_my_timestamp.sql executed
ChangeSet update_20220223::2::me ran successfully in 13ms
```

But when i try to use the function created by this changeset in annother changeset when creating an index

```
<changeSet author="me" id="3">
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">
        select count(*)
        from information_schema.constraint_column_usage
        where table_name = 'myEntity'  and constraint_name = 'description_day_timestamp_unique'
    </sqlCheck>
</preConditions>
<sql>
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX description_day_timestamp_unique ON myEntity."myProperty" USING btree (description, public.my_timestamp(insertdate));
</sql>
```

then i get the error

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: function 
public.my_timestamp(timestamp with time zone) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You 
might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found error. Parameter type was wrong

Comment: Please accept your answer, so that your question is marked as resolved.